# ERR_UNKNOWN in eclipse with jrebel

Tags: eclipse, weblogic-10.x, jrebel

hi i am using below script to start the sever

```
@echo off
set JAVA_OPTIONS=-javaagent:D:\eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-win32\eclipse\plugins\org.zeroturnaround.eclipse.embedder_5.1.3.SR1-201302011351\jrebel\jrebel.jar  %JAVA_OPTIONS%
call “%~dp0\startWebLogic.cmd” %*
```

if i did some change and click on synchronize all  i am geeting a msg

Jrebel remoting did not respond. The sever is up but is jrebel enabled?

but the changes were affecting and working fine.

to remove the msg i used

```
@echo off
set JAVA_OPTIONS=-javaagent:D:\eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-win32\eclipse\plugins\org.zeroturnaround.eclipse.embedder_5.1.3.SR1-201302011351\jrebel\jrebel.jar  -Drebel.remoting_plugin=true %JAVA_OPTIONS%
call “%~dp0\startWebLogic.cmd” %*
```

now am getting

ERR_UNKNOWN

with some Error-signature is not valid with some remoting exception.

and changes were not effecting.

what is mean by

-Drebel.remoting_plugin=true

it is searching for what..?

And how to remove that msg..?

Answer (score 0):

It was probably because of the configuration.
It looks like you were using JRebel remoting. This is used when you are developing in your local machine and application server is running on different machine.
In this case remote server needs to have -Drebel.remoting_plugin=true to start listening incoming file changes over HTTP post.
If signature was not valid then the remote server and IDE encryption keys were probably not in sync.